# Simpler way to check and call overloaded method

Tags: c#

```
private void SomeMethod(DerivedA something) {...}
private void SomeMethod(DerivedB something) {...}
private void SomeMethod(DerivedC something) {...}


BaseClass bc = somevariable;
if (bc is DerivedA) Somemethod(bc as DerivedA)
else if (bc is DerivedB) Somemethod(bc as DerivedB)
else if (bc is DerivedC) Somemethod(bc as DerivedC)
...
else if (bc is DerivedZZ) Somemethod(bc as DerivedZZ)
```

In .NET 3.5, there has got to be a simpler way, no?

Comment: Is `SomeMethod` something the object should be doing or is it something an outside force is doing with/to the object?

Comment: To clarify, the class I am working with is not DerivedX, but acts upon DerivedA... DerivedZ and calls methods to do different things. Basically, I am trying to avoid a large switch statement (or if/else) and decided to do SomeMethod(Derived A). I could have done SomeMethodActOnDerivedA, SomeMethodActOnDerivedB, etc. Think of it as a page with various user controls, and these user controls have a shared base class, but need to be populated and acted upon separately.

Comment: maybe typeof() can do the job for you?

Answer (score 4):

Isn't it appropriate to make SomeMethod a member method of your class ?

If DerivedA, DerivedB, etc... all share the same parent, then you can create this method as a virtual member method in the parent-class, and override it in the classes that inherit from it.  (This is not specific to .NET 3.5 -or any other .NET version whatsoever-, this is just one of the basic OOP features)

Like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public virtual void SomeMethod()
   {
       Console.WriteLine ("BaseClass");
   }
}

public class DerivedA : BaseClass
{
    public override SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DerivedA");
    }
}

public class DerivedB : BaseClass
{
    public override SomeMethod()
    {
       Console.WriteLine ("DerivedB");
    }
}

BaseClass bc = someVariable;

bc.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: See comment above. The class I am working with is not derived but acts upon derived objects

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BaseClass {
    public virtual void SomeMethod()
    {
    }
};

public class DerivedA : BaseClass {
    public override void someMethod()
    { //Do DerivedA things
    }
};
public class DerivedB : BaseClass {
    public override void someMethod()
    { //Do DerivedB things
    }
};
public class DerivedC : BaseClass {
    public override void someMethod()
    { //Do DerivedC things
    }
};
```

Then you can do:

```
BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
```

or

```
BaseClass bc = new DerivedA();
```

or

```
BaseClass bc = new DerivedB();
```

or

```
BaseClass bc = new DerivedC();
```

and just call:

```
bc.SomeMethod();
```

Even the BC type being BaseClass, if you instantiate as a derived, the derived method will be called. That means Inheritance and polymorphism.

this code is equilavent to yours.

Even yours, you can be better using typeof(); ;)

Comment: See comment above. The class I am working with is not derived but acts upon derived objects

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a slight rethink of how you are doing things; if you have some other class that needs to use this `BaseClass`, without knowing what type of derived class it contains until you call a method, that seems inefficient.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
     public abstract void InitializeAndDoOtherStuff();
}

public abstract class DerivedA
{
     public overload void InitializeAndDoOtherStuff()
     {
         // Initializes the control, pass whatever you need into this method, etc)
     }
}
```

In which case, your code looks like so:

```
BaseClass bc = someVariable;
bc.InitializeAndDoOtherStuff();
```

**OR**

This is a horrible idea from code management perspective, but you could do something like this:

```
 public class DerivedA : BaseClass, IControlA { }
 public class DerivedB : BaseClass, IControlB { }
 ...
```

And then your other class has overloads like so:

```
 public void SomeMethod(IControlA control) { }
 public void SomeMethod(IControlB control) { }
 ...
```

Then, in your code it would be as easy as:

```
BaseClass bc = someVariable;
SomeMethod(bc);
```

And overload resolution would take care of it because the appropriate interface is only on one derived class.

Answer (score 0):

I would also go with redesigning your classes like the others already stated but if you can't do that, you can use reflection to do the job

```
this.GetType().InvokeMember("SomeMethod", // Method name
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null, // DefaultBinder
    this, // object to call the method on
    new[]{ bc } // parameters to the method
    );
```

if SomeMethod is not a public instance method, you need to adapt the BindingFlags accordingly.

Comment: I cannot redesign classes that other people decided to do in the manner they chose. Based on my original question, knowing that I cannot change other people's code, is there anything that can be done to make this better?

Comment: Well, if u cant change the existing code, either write your own layer of abstraction for the existing code or if this is your only painpoint, use reflection to save yourself some typing